# Does a continuous function map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

I am self-learning Real Analysis from the text Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott. I'd like someone to verify if my proofs/counterexamples to below exercise are rigorous and correct.

> [Abbott, 4.4.6] Give an example of each of the following, or state that such a request is impossible. For any that are impossible, supply a short explanation of why this is the case.
>
> (a) A continuous function $\displaystyle f:( 0,1)\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $\displaystyle ( x_{n})$ such that $\displaystyle f( x_{n})$ is not a Cauchy sequence.
>
> (b) A uniformly continuous function $\displaystyle f:( 0,1)\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $\displaystyle ( x_{n})$ such that $\displaystyle f( x_{n})$ is not Cauchy.
>
> (c) A continuous function $\displaystyle f:[ 0,\infty )\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $\displaystyle ( x_{n})$ such that $\displaystyle f( x_{n})$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

***Proof.***

(a) Consider $\displaystyle f( x) =\frac{1}{x}$ defined and continuous on $\displaystyle ( 0,1)$.

Let $\displaystyle ( x_{n}) =\frac{1}{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\displaystyle ( 0,1)$, where $\displaystyle ( x_{n})\rightarrow 0$.

$\displaystyle f( x_{n})$ is an unbounded sequence, and so it's not Cauchy.

(b) This request is impossible.

Suppose $\displaystyle ( x_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\displaystyle ( 0,1)$. Then, for all $\displaystyle \delta  >0$, there exists $\displaystyle N\in \mathbf{N}$, $\displaystyle | x_{n} -x_{m}| < \delta $ for all $\displaystyle n >m\geq N$.

Since $\displaystyle f$ is uniformly continuous, for all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$, there exists $\displaystyle \delta  >0$, such that for all points $\displaystyle x,y$ satisfying $\displaystyle | x-y| < \delta $, we have $\displaystyle | f( x) -f( y)| < \epsilon $.

Consequently, for all $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$, there exists $\displaystyle N\in \mathbf{N}$, such that $\displaystyle | f( x_{n}) -f( x_{m})| < \epsilon $ for all $\displaystyle n >m\geq N$.

So, $\displaystyle f( x_{n})$ is Cauchy.

(c) This request is impossible.

$\displaystyle [ 0,\infty )$ is a closed set. For all Cauchy sequences $\displaystyle ( x_{n}) \subseteq [ 0,\infty )$ such that $\displaystyle ( x_{n})\rightarrow c$, the image sequence $\displaystyle f( x_{n})\rightarrow f( c)$. So, $\displaystyle f( x_{n})$ is Cauchy.

Comment: so what's the rule: cont $f: A \to \mathbb R$ maps cauchy to cauchy if ($f$ is uniform cont and $A$ is open)-or-(if $A$ is closed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers are correct. However, the justification for the third answer is not well written. I would put it as follows:

If $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence of elements of $[0,\infty)$, then it converges to some $c\in\Bbb R$ and, since $[0,\infty)$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$, $c\in[0,\infty)$. So, since $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(c)$ amd the fact that $\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges implies that it is a Cauchy sequence.

Another possibility consists in saying that if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then it is bounded. So, for some $M\in[0,\infty)$, $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):x_n\in[0,M]$. But the restriction of $f$ to $[0,M]$ is uniformly continuous, and uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

Comment: so what's the rule: cont $f: A \to \mathbb R$ maps cauchy to cauchy if ($f$ is uniform cont and $A$ is open)-or-(if $A$ is closed)?

Comment: Every uniformly continuous map from a subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ maps Cauchy sequence into Cauchy sequences.

Comment: is my statement wrong?

Comment: @BCLC No. I just told you that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then no other condition has to be added.

Comment: it's not an added condition....it's a different condition...? i'm asking about $A$ is closed but $f$ is not necessarily uniformly continuous...? wait is continuous $f$ on a closed set necessarily uniformly continuous?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, every continuous function from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: José Carlos Santos ah damn freudian slip lol. i knew the interval thing but i wanted to ask about closed set. edited comment. is cont $f$ on closed set but not necessarily closed interval necessarily uniformly continuous? i think continuous on closed but unbounded is not necessarily uniform iirc. thus i want to know now if cauchy preservation is implied by non-uniform cont but $A$ is closed

Comment: @BCLC If $A$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ and $f\colon A\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is continuous, then $f$ may well not be uniformly continuous (take, for instance, $A=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x$), but it still maps Cauchy seqeunces into Cauchy sequences. Because if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then it converges to some $x$ and, since $A$ is closed, $x\in A$. And now the continuity of $f$ implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$. And the sequence $\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, since it converges.

Comment: right yeah that's what i thought. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The writing on b could be improved a bit. You want to start with $\epsilon$, use the uniform continuity to get $\delta$, and then use that the sequence is Cauchy to get $N$ for that particular $\delta$. The need for this is easier to see when you realize that $N$ depends on $\delta$ and $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$.